# How to do I convert array of list column to struct in pyspark

Tags: json, pyspark

I need to create a json string of *non null* columns. I created a new column **col 3** as list or array with names of *non null* columns for each row. How do I create struct/json string using the column **col3**

| post code | addr | col3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 5678 |  | [post code] |
| 7877 | San jose | [post code, addr] |

Output expected

| col4 |
| --- |
| {"post code" : "5678"} |
| {"post code": "7877", "addr": "San jose"} |

as the column is not iterable I created a string by replacing **col3** values with **col(names)** for every element of aray and applied struct but it gave all array elements as 1 value.

As an alternate I created **col4** using

```
to_json(struct(when (col1 not null,col1),when (col2 not null,col2)))
```

However wanted to know if we can do by using only **col3**

Comment: your resulting struct can't have different number of fields in different rows.

Comment: if final column is struct type it doesn't allow to have diff columns in diff rows but when I do to json conversion it allows it

Answer (score 0):

```
df1 = df.withColumn("New", F.to_json(F.struct(F.col('post code'),F.col('addr'))))
df1.show(2,False)

+---------+--------+--------------------------------------+
|post code|addr    |New                                   |
+---------+--------+--------------------------------------+
|5678     |null    |{"post code":"5678"}                  |
|7877     |San jose|{"post code":"7877","addr":"San jose"}|
+---------+--------+--------------------------------------+
```